# How to pass canvas to pdf without deforming

Tags: javascript

I'm working with react and openlayers, a framework for maps of different types (vectors, wms, etc). The problem I have is that with my code to capture the canvas and pass it to pdf (through the library jsPDF) the image shown in the pdf is shown deformed, stretched ... that is, the same dimensions and proportions are not maintained .

For example, I have put a couple of logs to capture the width and height of the canvas before generating the pdf and I have these results: width: 3076px and height: 1672px and I have selected an A4 whose dimensions of 21.0 cm and 29.7 cm.

I've been looking at examples of how to resize the canvas element so that it does not deform but I can not. How can I scale the image without disproportionating? What do I have to keep in mind: are pixels and the other milestones one thing? The pixel density of the screen?

Here is my code, I would appreciate if you help me solve my problem because it is driving me crazy.

```
downloadImage = () => {

    var dims = {
        a0: [1189, 841],
        a1: [841, 594],
        a2: [594, 420],
        a3: [420, 297],
        a4: [297, 210],
        a5: [210, 148]
    };

    var format = this.state.format;
    var dim = dims[format];
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var pdf;
    if (this.state.orientation === 'portrait') {
        pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', undefined, format);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[1], dim[0]);
    } else {        
        pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
    }

    pdf.save(`map-${format}-${this.state.orientation}.pdf`);
}

CSS
-----
.map {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I is quite simple. Assuming you want to fit the image inside of the page bounds without clipping any part of it, you have 3 cases:

1. After scaling, the width of the image fits exactly inside the page width, and there is additional whitespace left in the vertical dimension. In this case you need to scale the image with ratio of `page.width/image.width`. How to know if this is the case? When `image.width/image.height > page.width/page.height`
2. After scaling, the height of the image fits exactly in the page bounds and there is white space left in the horizontal dimension, when `image.width/image.height < page.width/page.height`. Now you need to scale the image with the ratio of `page.height/image.height`
3. The image fits exactly both in horizontal and vertical direction (`image.width/image.height == page.width/page.height`). This can be reduced to either of the previous cases, because you can calculate the ratio both as `page.height/image.height` and `page.width/image.width`.

Keep in mind the page width and height depend on the page orientation, so you need to swap them for landscape. So assuming you already got the canvas dimensions and assigned it to imageWidth and imageHeight:

```
...
//I don't like hoisting, so let's declare the variables here ;)
var pageWidth, pageHeight;

if (this.state.orientation === 'portrait') {
    pageWidth = dim[1];
    pageHeight = dim[0]
} else {        
    pageWidth = dim[0];
    pageHeight = dim[1]
}
var ratio = imageWidth/imageHeight >= pageWidth/pageHeight ? pageWidth/imageWidth : pageHeight/imageHeight;
pdf = new jsPDF(this.state.orientation, undefined, format);
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imageWidth * ratio, imageHeight * ratio);
...
```

This doesn't take into account any margins but I am sure you can take care for them if needed.